# Concatenate multiple column into single in a resulted query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I need a help in adding multiple column in single (DB2) after a resulted query

My resulted query looks like,

```
EMPI   HRS  MTS  SDS
-------------------
sam    12   10   10
tukai  10   05   02
```

Now, I want this output instead:

```
empid   Totaltimetaken
----------------------
sam     12:10:10
tukai   10:05:02
```

First query:

```
SELECT
    empid
    ,TOTALSECONDS/3600 AS HRS
    ,(MOD(TOTALSECONDS, 3600) /60) AS MTS
    ,(MOD(TOTALSECONDS, 60)) AS SDS
FROM 
    (SELECT
        SUM(duration) AS TOTALSECONDS
        ,empid
     FROM table
     GROUP BY empid)
```

From the above query result, I now want to add the columns: `empid, hrs, mts, sds`.

I used this query but not getting result. Any help...

```
SELECT 
    TMP1.emp
    ,('0'||(TOTALSECONDS.TMP1)/3600)||':'||
    ('0'||(MOD(TOTALSECONDS.TMP1),3600)/60) ':'||
    MOD(TOTALSECONDS.TMP1),60) AS TOTALTIMETAKEN
    ,TMP1.TOTALSECONDS
FROM
   (SELECT 
       EMPID emp,
       SUM(DURATION) AS TOTALSECONDS
    FROM table
    GROUP BY EMPID) TMP1
```

This is for IBM DB2.

Comment: Which DB? SqlServer or DB2?

Comment: This query has additional problems - `'0'` is being prefixed for hours/minutes in _all_ cases, even if it already has two digits, and _never_ for seconds (ie, you'll get things like `'01:023:0'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using TMP1 as a prefix-

```
SELECT TMP1.emp, TMP1.TOTALSECONDS,
           ('0' || (TMP1.TOTALSECONDS) / 3600) || ':' ||
           ('0' || (MOD(TMP1.TOTALSECONDS, 3600) / 60) ':' ||
           MOD(TMP1.TOTALSECONDS, 60) AS TOTALTIMETAKEN
FROM (SELECT EMPID emp, SUM(DURATION) AS TOTALSECONDS
      FROM table
      GROUP BY EMPID) TMP1
```

Comment: Thanks. It says An unexpected token "," was found following "D(TMP1.TOTALSECONDS)".  Expected tokens may include:  "+".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Edited extra brackets in the query

Answer (score -1):

This should get you on the right track....

```
Select One, Two
from Table
```

will result in 2 columns that will look like

```
|One|   |Two|
  1       2
```

-

```
 Select Cast(One as varchar(30)) + '_' + Cast(Two as varchar(30)) as 'Concatenated'
 from Table
```

result will look like

```
|Concatenated|
     1_2
```

*Note this is for SQL Server

Comment: Perhaps because `+` is not the supported operator for character concatenation, `||` (two "pipe" characters) is?  Or the fact that they already know how to convert to character?  Look closer at the question - what is the query actually doing... or not, in this case?